# Centos 6 - Allow sudo composer self-update for user without password

Tags: permissions, centos6, sudo, composer

I'm trying to allow my wheel group user to run `sudo composer self-update` without a prompt for a password for my deploy script.

I have added the bottom line below to my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But it is still prompting for a password.

Removing the next line up removed my ability to sudo any command as the user.

Have I done something wrong? Do I need to restart something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it works if I run the command and specify the location exactly:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/composer self-update
```